# Generate an array of 0 and 1 with given conditions

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

How does one generate an array according to value in cells? For example, if (A1,B1) is (3,0), (A2,B2) is (2,1), and (A3,B3) is (2,0) (this first number depicts how many of the second number in the array), how does one obtain an array of {0,0,0,1,1,0,0}? In a general form, if I have (i,0), (j,1), and (k,0), I would like to get an array of {i zeros,j ones, k zeros}.

Several Excel functions can return an array, such as OFFSET, INDEX. I don't know any way to concatenate arrays.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for an output in another cell? e.g. a formula like `="{"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1&" ",A1),REPT(B2&" ",A2),REPT(B3&" ",A3)))," ",", ")&"}"` will generate the output in string/text format.

Comment: @Shrivallabha.redij I think the formula gives a string, not an array.

Comment: Yes, which is what I have stated in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you step through this with Evaluate Formula, you should see that it generates an array as requested:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},MATCH(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUM(A:A))),IFERROR(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1,0,0,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)))-1,1))+1,1),1)))))
```

must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Basically it uses offset and subtotal to generate an array containing a running total of the values in column A, then uses match and index to lookup numbers from 1 to 7 in this array and find the corresponding number in column B. Not very elegant because I had to use an offset with a height of zero to get the first value in the lookup array, then iferror to set the resulting #REF! to 1.

It's a separate question of how to concatenate such an array - if you have Excel 2019 or 365 you can use Textjoin.

**EDIT**

If you wish to avoid using volatile functions like Offset, you can get the running totals of column A another way, by developing a 2d array as follows and using Mmult:

```
0 0 0

1 0 0

1 1 0
```

Formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},MATCH(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUM(A:A))),
MMULT(IF(ROW(A1:INDEX($1:$1048576,COUNT(A:A),COUNT(A:A)))>COLUMN(A1:INDEX($1:$1048576,COUNT(A:A),COUNT(A:A))),1,0),
A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)))+1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. You said the formula "lookup numbers from 1 to 7." Which part of the formula does that? I can't see it.

Comment: Possible to "hard code" the formula, i.e. use cell value directly without using its address? For example, use 3, not A1, 0, not B1, etc.

Comment: In answer to your first comment, ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUM(A:A)) . SUM(A:A) equals 7, so the INDEX part gives a reference to cell A7 and this works out to ROW(A1:A7) i.e. numbers 1 to 7.

Comment: Re your second comment, you couldn't do it the same way if the cell values were hard-coded as an array constant because OFFSET requires a cell address to offset from so it would be a challenge...in other words, at time of writing I don't know how you would do it!

Comment: I found that using 1, instead of {1}, the formula still works.

Comment: Yes, the {1} is not strictly necessary, but (in my opinion) it's a usage that many people will recognise from the early references on this and will say 'aha, the person is trying to coerce Index into yielding an array here'.

Comment: BTW I think there may be a way to answer your second comment about generating an array from hard-coded values, but it is a separate answer needing a different approach. Plz consider accepting or upvoting any answer that addresses your current question, then posting a separate question about the hard-coding.

Comment: OK. I'll post another question about using absolute value instead of cell address to get the desire result in this post.

Comment: I usually flag and accept as answer. But in this case, two answers all answered my question. Which one to accept? I believe I can only accept one, not two, answer. If I accept one, the other might be offended because his/her answer also works. I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: TBH I've reached a stage in life where I'm not that bothered about the rep, so perfectly happy if you accept the other answer which is rather nice and a bit shorter than mine. Or I think you've got enough rep just to upvote both answers?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data housed in `A1:B3` as in :

```
A    B
3    0
2    1
2    0
```

In `D1`, enter formula :

```
=LOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(A1:A10))),IFERROR(SUMIF(OFFSET(A$1,,,ROW(A1:A10)-1),"<>")+1,1),B1:B3)
```

Highlight `D1`, press keystroke F9 and cell `D1` will give an array result :

```
={0;0;0;1;1;0;0}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. if I want to "hard code" the formula, i.e. not using cell addresses but using their values directly (use 3, not A1, 0, not B1, etc.), can it be done?

Comment: When I evaluate OFFSET(A$1,,,ROW(A1:A10)-1), the first element is #REF!. Yet, it doesn't affect the result. The whole formula doesn't give an error. I wonder why.