# Generating an array using absolute values instead of cell references

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226903/generate-an-array-of-0-and-1-with-given-conditions/59229218?noredirect=1#comment104689715_59229218)

I have (3,0), (2,1), and (2,0) in rows 1 to 3. There are ways to generate the array of {0,0,0,1,1,0,0} using cell addresses. (See the reference above.)

Now, my question is can the same array be generated NOT using the cell references but using the three pairs of the numbers only?

NOTE: In the real case, there may be up to six pairs of numbers, A1:B1 to A6:B6, and up to 2880 array elements.

Excel 2010

```
     A    B
1    3    0
2    2    1
3    2    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed as in the edit to my answer to the original question, by generating an array as follows:

```
0 0 0

1 0 0

1 1 0
```

and using Mmult instead of Offset to get the running totals of the first column of numbers.

```
=SUM(INDEX(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,2),N(IF({1},MATCH(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUM(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1)))),
MMULT(IF(ROW(A1:INDEX($1:$1048576,COUNT(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1)),COUNT(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1))))>
COLUMN(A1:INDEX($1:$1048576,COUNT(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1)),COUNT(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1)))),1,0),INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1))+1)))))
```

[image]

If you hard-code the number of pairs of numbers instead of using Countif to count them, the formula is shorter:

```
=SUM(INDEX(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,2),N(IF({1},MATCH(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUM(INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1)))),
MMULT(IF(ROW(A1:INDEX($1:$1048576,3,3))>
COLUMN(A1:INDEX($1:$1048576,3,3)),1,0),INDEX({3,0;2,1;2,0},0,1))+1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. Since in my real case, there'll be 2880 elements in the array, I guess it is not practical to use this method, although it works.

Comment: I've tested it with an array like this {480,0;480,1;480,0;480,1;480,0;480,1} (6 pairs of numbers generating a 2880-element array) and it works fine. The 2d array it  uses is only the same size as the number of pairs i.e. 6X6.